# I want to know how we can set pagination on static images in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

**i tried basic paginatio**
`i tried simple pagination code`

```
enter code here dwd
```

> enter code here*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

I am new in asp.net mvc. I want to add pagination on images that are static lets suppose i kept 20 images in folder and i want to fetch these images from folder and show into view in a sequence on click of pagination numbers .
 I have code this in view.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="row products products-big">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                <div class="product">
                                    <div class="image"> <a 
href="@Url.Action("StoreProductDetails", "Store")"><img src="~/img/Quran.png" alt="" class="img-fluid image1"></a></div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h3 class="h5"><a href="@Url.Action("StoreProductDetails", "Store")">Holy Quran<br />with translation </a></h3>
                                            <p class="price">$143.00</p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                <div class="product">
                                    <div class="image"><a href="@Url.Action("StoreProductDetails", "Store")"><img src="~/img/tasbi.png" alt="" class="img-fluid image1"></a></div>
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3 class="h5"><a href="@Url.Action("StoreProductDetails", "Store")">Tasbi</a></h3>
                                        <p class="price">
                                            <del>$280</del> $143.00
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Hi. You can read about pagination  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
And you also can read from the folder how many files you have so you can put the number into a pagination value